# Is it possible to load large data directly into numpy int8 array using h5py?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, h5py

I have a very large data file (1000 by 1400000 array) that contains integers of 0, 1, 2 and 4. It takes a very long time to load this big data into a numpy array using h5py because my memory(4GB) cannot hold that much and the program uses the swap space. Since there are only 4 numbers in the data, I want to use a 8 bit integer array. Currently I load the data and convert it to a 8 bit int array after that.

```
with h5py.File("largedata", 'r') as f:

    variables = f.items()
    # extract all data
    for name, data in variables:
        # If DataSet pull the associated Data
        if type(data) is h5py.Dataset:
            value = data.value
            if(name == 'foo'):
                # convert to 8 bit int
                nparray = np.array(value, dtype=np.int8)
```

Is it possible to load the data directly into a 8bit int array to save memory while loading?

Comment: Try `data.value.astype(np.int8)`

Comment: Or consider loading slices.  Whats the data type on the file?

Answer (score 2):

From the dataset docs page

```
 astype(dtype)

 Return a context manager allowing you to read data as a particular type. 
 Conversion is handled by HDF5 directly, on the fly:

>>> dset = f.create_dataset("bigint", (1000,), dtype='int64') 
>>> with dset.astype('int16'): 
      out = dset[:] 
>>> out.dtype 
       =dtype('int16')
```